# Grunt recursive copy

Tags: gruntjs

I'm setting up a Grunt script that needs to copy and reorganise directories of images from A to B. Simple enough.

**Directory structure:**

components

- componentA

  - js
  - img

    - imgfolderA
    - imgfolderB
  - css
- componentB

  - js
  - img

    - imgfolderA

Each img directory could contain other directories and directories within those directories to help organise the images.

I want to use Grunt to take all those images and put them under one directory (assets/img):

assets

- img

  - dirA

    - imgfolderA
    - imgfolderB
  - dirB

    - imgfolderA

Any ideas on how could I do this in grunt without specifying each component directory (it needs to be fully automated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple using [`grunt.file.expand`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand).

Just pass matching glob patterns (e.g. `**/img/**`), and then recurse on the returned matching file values to copy.

Comment: Ooh interesting, thanks. Can't say whether this has solved my issue or not as I'm unsure of how to use the API. I'll attempt to learn it and see if it works!

Comment: If you look for a grunt task, then checkout `grunt-contrib-copy`. You should be able to apply the same logic I explained here. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy

Comment: Ok so so far I have this: http://pastie.org/8372295. It's not working at present (doesn't actually copy the files). Half the problem is I don't understand how to interact with grunt.file.copy, and the other half of the problem is I expect I'm not using grunt.file.expand correctly. Is this however, how you visualised solving this problem?

Answer (score 22):

know it's a bit late but this should do the job, use 'grunt-contrib-copy' like so

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy: {
      production: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: "componentA/img/imgfolderA/",
            src: ["*.*", "**/*.*"],
            dest: "./assets/img/dirA/",
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: "componentB/img/imgfolderB/",
            src: ["*.*", "**/*.*"],
            dest: "./assets/img/dirB/",
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  // Production Build Tools
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  // Default Production Build task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
};
```

ps magic is in the files objects, there not very well documented, but the documentation is here, after one or two reads it makes sense honest!

grunt-contrib-copy setup: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy (the readme at the bottom)

files object setup: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

task setup: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

Comment: Using `src: ['*', '**']` was sufficient for me.

Comment: @AramKocharyan Does single asterisk `'*'` represent current directory or all files in current directory? and double asterisk `'**'` represent all directories/files along with recursive nature?