# How to uglify all javascript files in subfolders/subdirectory using Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I'm using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#package.json) to uglify javascipt files in my project.

**Question:**

How to uglify all javascript files in subfolders/subdirectory?

**What I've done in Gruntfile.js**:

Currently it will only uglify those javascript files in js folder since I'm using src: 'js/*.js'. However I have other directories in js folder that has javascript files:

```
├── CommonUtil.js
├── Paging
│   ├── dirPagination.js
│   └── dirPagination.tpl.html
├── angular-chart.js
├── angular-elastic-input.min.js
├── angularAlt.js
├── authenticationChallengeHandler
│   └── loginChallengeHandler.js
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // define source files and their destinations
        uglify: {
            files: { 
                src: 'js/*.js',  // source files mask
                dest: 'jsm/',    // destination folder
                expand: true,    // allow dynamic building
                flatten: true,   // remove all unnecessary nesting
                ext: '.min.js'   // replace .js to .min.js
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js:  { files: 'js/*.js', tasks: [ 'uglify' ] },
        }
    });

// load plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

// register at least this one task
grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'uglify' ]);


};
```

Comment: Perhaps this will show you how? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138329/grunt-recursive-copy

Comment: @mplungjan thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use glob patterns like: `src: '/**/*.js'`

Comment: Thx for replying.. I've modified my Guntfile.js with scr: '**/*.js' however, i'm hitting this error after i run grunt in the terminal. JS_Parse_Error {
  message: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (.)',
  filename: '../*.js',
  line: 1,
  col: 0,
  pos: 0,
  stack:

Comment: You need to mention a root folder. Could you try `/**/*.js` like mentioned?

Comment: Hitting this: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory but i think your answer should work...

Comment: Ah that means there's some memory leakage and you need to look into your code and see what's causing it. Something is probably running in an infinite loop causing the JS heap to run out of memory

Comment: Turn on --verbose logging, either to the console or to a log file and it might tell you which .js files have errors and how to fix them.